# SQLiteDatabase How to join two strings in SQLiteDatabase query and SimpleCursorAdapter?

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

**Table fields:**

_id, street, house_nr

**query:**

```
mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_STREET_NAME,
                KEY_HOUSE_NUMBER}, null, null, null, null, KEY_ROWID + " DESC");
```

**SimpleCursorAdapter:**

```
    Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllRows();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] from = new String[] { HistoryDbAdapter.KEY_STREET_NAME};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };

    SimpleCursorAdapter entries =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.history_row, c, from, to);
    setListAdapter(entries);
```

How to add one combined string from two db fields into R.id.text1 to show full address.

**example:**

```
street = "Android street"
house_nr = "911"
```

**then:**

```
R.id.text1 = "Android street 911"
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways:

- Concat both column names in the query: KEY_STREET_NAME + " || " + KEY_HOUSE_NUMBER. I would use a rawQuery then.
- Use a custom adapter.

Comment: hmm maybe query.. or maybe someone have custom adapter like i need :D

Comment: It's your descision. For a simple list like you've shown I would change the query. However, if this answers your question don't forget to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```
public class HistoryCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public HistoryCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.history_row, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Cursor c = getCursor();
        c.moveToPosition(position);
        int street_index = c.getColumnIndex(HistoryDbAdapter.KEY_STREET_NAME);
        int house_nr_index = c.getColumnIndex(HistoryDbAdapter.KEY_HOUSE_NUMBER);
        holder.text.setText(String.format("%s %s", c.getString(street_index), c.getString(house_nr_index)));
        return convertView;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
    }
}
```

Thats my first time. Maybe it can be writed more simple? maybe any speed suggestions?

Comment: a very clean example of a custom CursorAdapter can be found here: http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/11/16/creating-a-custom-cursoradapter-for-android/